# Could my computer have downloaded some sort of virus or malware after clicking this button?

Tags: malware, virus, virus-removal

I went to the website: katsokos.com, and was shown this page:

[image]

I stupidly clicked on the verification button and was redirected to the chrome store page for some chrome plugin, as well as the website page itself redirecting to something else. Could this have infected my computer somehow?

Comment: In theory yes, but the Chrome Store redirect shouldn't worry you as that is exactly what the text says under the button

Comment: Yeah, but it still seems pretty sketchy. I reloaded the page after I did this, and I redirected me to another site telling me to install more stuff.

Comment: @JackCeroni The link katsokos.com redirects to a page which is marked as selling. I could not see any security check as mentioned above. COuld you post the URL in the question?

Comment: @KolappanNathan Yeah, I tried going back onto the website, and it redirected me to that page as well. Interestingly enough, if I reloaded the page a few times, I would be redirected back to a page that looks identical to the “I am human” page, but is a different URL. I honestly have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer yes it could (doesn't mean it did).  I haven't taken the time to investigate the webpage or the button etc but as it apparently did what it said it would do on the page I wouldn't be too worried.

To learn more you could use a clean virtual machine (that is fully patched) and go poke around and see what it tries to do.  If you don't want to do that at least run a virus scan.

Comment: Yeah I ran an AVG scan, but I just wanted to make sure. When I reloaded the page, I got redirected to yet a third website asking me to download more stuff. Is there a way to know if anything was downloaded after I clicked the button?

Answer (score 0):

If it redirected you to a Chrome Web Store page, then the site was probably trying to trick you into installing a malicious Chrome extension. If the page already exploited you through a browser zero-day exploit, then it wouldn't need to do this, unless the zero-day exploit specifically required linking you to the Chrome Web Store. Any exploit involving the Chrome Web Store would probably involve getting your browser to install a Chrome extension. If no extensions were added to your browser, then it seems like it wasn't that case. Most likely, the attacker hoped you would blindly install the extension at the linked Chrome Web Store page. If you didn't do that (you say you closed the Chrome Web Store page immediately), then you're probably safe.